# How to add time line using normal list in SharePoint

Tags: list, design

Is it possible to add time line web-part using normal custom list or any other solution to implement through normal list

Answer (score 1):

If you have a column for Title, Start Date, & End Date (not necessarily with those column names), you could create a Gantt View of the list. This lets you select your start and end date columns, and represents it graphically.

Comment: Are you sure, we can use Gantt view for the time line..because I couldn't get the view while configuring timeline.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. In my list (not the webpart), I clicked 'create new view', then 'Gantt View'. You can configure the settings there. Then, on the page you would the webpart, insert the webpart. Then edit the webpart, and change the view to the Gantt view that you created.

Answer (score 0):

It's not part of the list, it's a separate webpart. On the page where you want the timeline insert a new web part, and under content rollup you will find the timeline.

** Edit **

You can't bind it to a "custom list" type.  You can however create a task list and then extend it with the columns you need.  This would let you use the timeline with that list.

You can't just add the task content type either - it has to start as a task list to work.

Comment: Yes, But it should be linked to task list..I want a way to use it with normal list.

Comment: How can I extend lsit with column..can you please help me out for this